# How to pass in arguments in debounce

Tags: javascript, arguments, closures, debouncing

```
const debounce = (func) => {
    return (arg) => {
        let timeoutId;
        if (timeoutId){
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            func(arg);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

function hello(name){
    console.log("hello " + name);
}

input.addEventListener("input", debounce(hello));
```

In this example how am I suppose to debounce and call the `hello` function with a debounce and the name `"Brian"`.

On code line 2 `return (arg) => {` what is the code to pass an argument in the variable?

I get that `debounce(hello);` calls the debounce function but how am I suppose to pass in a variable so it gets stored in `(arg)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you return a function from a function, you have two sets of arguments: those to the outer function and those to the inner function, so the pattern is essentially

```
debounce(someFunction)("argument 1 to someFunction", "argument 2 to someFunction");
```

You can spread this over a few lines. The pattern is known as [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying).

Note that your debouncer function isn't correct. It's delaying, but not batching updates because the `timeoutId` is local to the returned function, defeating the purpose of the closure.

Also, using `...args` instead of `args` and making the timeout a parameter rather than hardcoding it in the function makes the debounce a bit more resuable.

Here's a minimal example of all of this:

```js
const debounce = (func, timeout=1000) => {
  let timeoutId;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      func(...args);
    }, timeout);
  };
};

const hello = name => console.log("hello " + name);
const debouncedHello = debounce(hello);
document.querySelector("input")
  .addEventListener("input", e => debouncedHello(e.target.value));
```

```html
<input value="test">
```

Answer (score 2):

VanillaJS solution.

```
function debounce(func, timeout = 300) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, timeout);
  };
}

const updateQuantityDebounce = debounce((a,b) => updateNewValue(a,b));

function updateNewValue(id, quantity) {
  console.log({ id, quantity }); // do network requests here.
}
```

To use it , suppose from inside a click eventlistener

```
   function fn() {
        updateQuantityDebounce(id, newValue)
    }
```